# Whats the best way to switch user and run multiple commands?

Tags: bash

Whats the best way to switch user run **multiple commands** and send output from all commands to file?

Needs to be done in one line so something like:

`sudo -u user (command1; command2; command3; command4; command5) > out.log 2&1`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running multiple commands separated by semicolons requires a shell.  To get such shell features, you must invoke a shell like, in this case, bash:

```
sudo -u user bash -c 'command1; command2; command3; command4; command5' > out.log 2&1
```

Here, `sudo -u user bash` runs `bash` under `user`.  The `-c` option tells `bash` which commands to run.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo -u user command1 > outFile; command2 >> outFile; command3 >> outFile; command3 >> outFile; command4 >> outFile;
```

If you want subsequent command to not execute if the previous one failed then...

```
command1 > outFile && command2 >> outFile && command3 >> outFile && command3 >> outFile && command4 >> outFile;
```

Note that command1 output is piped to the outFile by '>' (which will create a file and add output) whereas all subsequent commands are piping through '>>' (which will append the output)